# Debugging before_filter with Pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I have the a before_filter inside my controller:

```
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show,:index]

  def create
    #method code
  end
```

My question is: how do I debug the before_filter method (authenticate_user!) for the create method using pry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
before_filter :bla

def bla
  binding.pry
  authenticate_user!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up disabling the before_filter and just added the authenticate_user! method to the first line of my create method - it pretty much did the trick.